# Multiplicative Vs Additive (PID) Feedback Loops

Tags: pid-control, feedback-loop

I normally think of PID feedback loops as being additive. This might not be quite standard, but, e.g. for a simple discrete-time proportional gain loop,

$$
C_{t+1}=C_{t}+G(S-M_t) \tag 1
$$

Where $C_{t}$ is the input at time stamp $t$, $G$ is my loop gain, $S$ is my setpoint or desired measured value, and $M_t$ is the measured value. Then of course one could add integrator and derivative terms, but the way I've written it we are adding the PID response to our control variable.

However sometimes in the right context it makes more physical sense to implement a multiplicative feedback loop, e.g.

$$
C_{t+1} = \frac{S}{M_t} C_{t} \tag 2
$$

However while there are books written about PID feedback loops I realized that I'm not sure I've ever heard of a formal description or discussion of feedback loops that operate like this, such that I'm not sure i even know the right words to search for. Does this have a name? Are there any good references for this?

Comment: Little confused on what C is the input to ... it may be easier to communicate this if you draw a block diagram and identify your terms from the diagram. Show everything in your loop, not just your "controller". Can you do that?